# How can I figure out if my HDD is actually on or off now? Win10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, power-management

I've set "Turn off hard disk after" value in the Power Options. But when I open my HDD in the File Explorer it happens instantly that's why I'm not sure if it's actually on or off at the moment. Please tell me if it's possible to somehow figure it out.

P.S. Some people think that's a bad idea to shut down HDDs because it'll trash their heads. My HDD is used only  from time to time during the backups while my PC is turned on most of the time.

Comment: ["Turn off hard disk after: Never" Is this a bad idea?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/924462-turn-off-hard-disk-after-never-is-this-a-bad-idea)

Comment: See answer by Lunatik and Zak B>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/400213/see-if-hdd-is-in-sleep-mode-for-windows

Comment: With respect to heads, most drives park the heads when powered off to prevent damage. Set your drive to power off after inactive for some time. Wait.  You should be able to hear that it spins down.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command in the *Powershell*:

```
get-disk
```

Look at the *OperationalStatus* column

[image]

References:

- [Get-Disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-disk?view=win10-ps)
- ["Turn off hard disk after: Never" Is this a bad idea?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/924462-turn-off-hard-disk-after-never-is-this-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Which output column shows it is powered off?

Comment: *OperationalStatus* column

Comment: Add that to your answer please. Maybe a screenshot if you can.

Comment: Ir seems to me that a disk could be online but "off" which is why it is so instantly available.

Comment: There is also caching. Anything you've been using is in memory. Therefore continuing a task the data will come from the cache so will be instant. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-caching